# CGAffineTransform on TabBar in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitabbar

I am attempting to recede a tab bar when a user pans another view similar to what happens in the player view in the Spotify app. However, when I try to use `CGAffineTransform` on the tab bar it has no effect. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
@objc func handleSlidePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .changed {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        footerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: translation.y) //Works

        if let tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar {
            tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -translation.y) //Dosen't work
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference for effect**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCb8L.jpg

Comment: It works for me, try with gesture.translation of tabBarController's view

Comment: Are you using a UITabBarController or a UIViewController with a UITabBar as a property?

Comment: Running that function in a UIViewController thats part of my UITabBarController

Comment: Yeah i'm using UITabBarController